# How to use different login redirect paths for different roles/policy in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I want to use different redirects for different roles. Is there a possible way to do that without creating custom middleware or filter?

Comment: you have to provide actual problem here. what did you already tried and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You could set two AuthenticationSchemes with different redirect path as below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Cookie1")
    .AddCookie("Cookie1", op => {
        op.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Home/Test1");
        
    })

    .AddCookie("Cookie2", op => op.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Home/Test2"));
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Policy1", policy => policy.RequireClaim("SomeClaim"));
    options.AddPolicy("Policy2", policy => policy.RequireClaim("SomeClaim"));
});
```

Add the Attribute on Action:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie1", Policy = "Policy1")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie2", Policy = "Policy2")]
```